# PHP: is it mandatory to unset objects you create via "new"?

Tags: php

If during a function, I `new AnObject` - do I have to `unset` it before the function exist? or is it done automatically using reference counting?

Comment: [Scope rules](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) apply to object instances in exactly the same way they apply to any other variable

Comment: Got an example of what you're asking?

Comment: I had run some command line programs that were memory intensive.  As such, doing the unset, or at least setting to null, allowed the garbage collection to run a lot sooner, and prevented crashes when I exhausted memory.  I was processing about 1.2 Gb of data, so the classes needed to be assigned to null for garbage collection to work in a timely manner. This was however, on PHP 5.4.x.

Comment: I have no experience of `php` but this looks like something that could be looked up quite easily without the need to hit S.O?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [garbage collection](http://www.hackingwithphp.com/18/1/10) should take care of it for you:

> PHP performs garbage collection at three primary junctures:
>
> When you tell it to
>
> When you leave a function
>
> When the script ends

So no, you should not *have to* unset anything, but you can if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

When unsettling a variable it seems that you only are marking the value for the garbage collector. And when you're exiting your function's scope, the reference counter will be decremented, and your object will be marked to be deleted, having the same result that you would have calling the unset.

https://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php